# Making synchronous call in Angular 2 with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, firebase-storage

I have a service which needs to upload image to Firebase storage first and return downloadurl. After getting download url I need to store it into Firebase Realtime Database.

But the problem here is Firebase calls are asynchronous.

This is my code :

```
 addCategory(category){

let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`category/${category.img_name}`);
    //Upload file

    storageRef.put(category.url)
      .then((snapshot) => {
    // Here i will get download url
        var downloadUrl = snapshot.downloadURL;
        category.category_icon = downloadUrl.toString();

      })

     //Problem occurs here return is executed before .then statement and my download url becomes undefined.

        return this.http.post('https://app_name.cloudfunctions.net/api/products',body,{headers:headers})
        .map(res =>res.json());
  }
```

So I need to know Is there any possibility to stop making this call (storageRef.put()) synchronous so that my return statement should trigger only after completion of .put() call.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

when you want to wait while execution completed you should return the URL from the first "then" then the second "then" will execute just after the first "then" finished

```
addCategory(category){



let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`category/${category.img_name}`);
        //Upload file
        return storageRef.put(category.url)
              .then((snapshot) => {
                return snapshot.downloadURL
              }).then(url => { // this will excute after you get the url
                  category.category_icon = url.toString();
                  return this.http.post('https://app_name.cloudfunctions.net/api/products',body,{headers:headers})
                 .map(res =>res.json());


                  })
}
```

you call addCategory like this

```
addCategory(category).then(obs => {
 obs.subscribe(res => {
 // add your code here
})
    })
```

Comment: Yeah!! I tried that too. But my component which is call this service function addCategory(category) is expecting Return statement. So i can't make http post inside .then(). If I write so its not working. Because my calling function uses . subscribe

Comment: @PraveenCool make not not expect a return statement. until you do, you will be unable to solve your problem. you should instead make it expect a promise that it can chain from.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research i found the solution.

```
    addCategory(category){

       // this.uploadImage(category);

    //Upload file


    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`category/${category.img_name}`);

    storageRef.put(category.url)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        var downloadUrl = snapshot.downloadURL;
        category.category_icon = downloadUrl;
        let body = this.categoryRefService.buildRequestBody(category);
        let headers = this.categoryRefService.setHeaders();

        return this.http.post('https://us-central1-app-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/products',body,{headers:headers})
        .map(res =>res.json())
  // Just moved my http request inside firebase promise and subscribed to http call here
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.result = data
      });

      })

  }
```